# Remove water run off stains on concrete

Tags: concrete, drainage

We had some planters installed in our backyard and the drainage wasn’t really thought through well. So when it rained, some water stains were left on our concrete.

[image]What’s a good way to remove these stains?

Comment: Have you tried something like *30 second cleaner*?

Comment: usually those are calc deposits, vinegar can remove that

Comment: Or pressure washer?